# Add a Privacy View on React-Native application

Tags: ios, react-native

I am building a React-Native application and I need to hide the content of the application screen when it goes to the task manager or when the app goes in the background, for privacy reason.

I'm using the React-Native `AppState` to display a privacy `View` on top of everything which hides its content when the application is not active, and I remove the privacy `View` when it's back to an active state.

It works fine.

However, I've noticed the application becomes `inactive` when the Touch ID dialog shows up, which displays my privacy `View` during the Touch ID process and this is not the expected behavior for me.

[image]

The pinky screen is the privacy `View` here.

I tried to show the privacy `View` only when the app state becomes `background` but this happens too late and the screen is not hidden in the task manager.

This is how my component looks like:

```
export default class AppPrivacy extends Component {
  state = {
    enabled: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
  }

  handleAppStateChange = (newAppState) => {
    this.setState({ enabled: newAppState !== 'active' });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      this.state.enabled && <View style={styles.container} />
    );
  }
}
```

I'm wondering what would be the best way to display that privacy `View` only when the app goes in the task manager or in the background, but not when the app shows the Touch ID dialog?

FYI I use `react-native-fingerprint-scanner` for Touch ID.

I've also explored the package `react-native-privacy-snapshot` to create a privacy view but it behaves the exact same way unfortunately.

Thanks!